# How to read SQL bit datatype and write it to a file in c#

Tags: c#, t-sql, encoding, cdc

I am using cdc pattern in SQL Server to track data changes in a database. When I read `__start_lsn`,which is `bit` datatype in sql, with the help of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(context.SomeCdcTable.__start_lsn)` the result is: 
`\u0000捫܀䘊Ѐ`. I tried `UTF32` , `Unicode` and other schemes but no progress at all. would appreciate any hint, thanks.

Comment: A `bit` in SQL Server can only be 1 or 0 (or null), so usually you'd use it as a `bool` (or `bool?`) in C#. What are you trying to achieve by encoding it?

Comment: Why do you expect a bit to be an encoded string? Convert it to bool first and then use one of two strings based on the value

Comment: I want to save the `__start_lsn` on a file(say lsn.json). With the help of this file I can say to which record my app has read data.

Comment: I think you got confused. I have 2 databases, when data in  table A of first db changes, I need to change data in the second db accordingly. I am using cdc to capture data. why saving `__start_lsn` in a file? because I need to know to which record in A_cdc_table I have read data, and based on this file I can say whether I have fetched new changed data or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `__$start_lsn` column has a `binary(10)` data type (not `bit`). This column does not store character data (in any encoding), it's just a binary number. If you want to convert it to a string (for storing in a JSON file), you can use the CONVERT function specifying 1 as the style:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(22),sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('YourTable'),1)
```